# Curl PUT in PHP

Tags: php, curl, put

I need to "translate" this curl in php, but I can't do it:

```
curl --proxy proxy_ip:port --proxy-user user:psw- --user "admin":"admin" \
  -H 'Content-type: application/json' -X PUT \
  -d '{"installInHw":"true", "name":"flow1", "node": {"id":"00:00:00:4e:54:32:33:0f", "type":"OF"}, "ingressPort":"2", "etherType": "0x800", "protocol": "6", "tpDst": "80", "priority":"65535","actions":["DROP"]}' \
  'indirizzo_http'
```

Can anybody helps me?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you heard of Manual? No, no worries here it is: http://www.php.net//manual/en/ref.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

[PHP curl](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.curl.php) has these options to proxy requests.

```
// $data = '{"installInHw":"true", "name":"flow1", "nod" ... ;
//$loginpassw = 'admin:admin';
//$proxy_ip = '192.168.0.50';
//$proxy_port = '8080';
//$url = 'http://example.com';    

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $loginpassw);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if(!$response) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to set the request body content type.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer.
I tried 2 different ways:

OPTION 1: like you suggest
OPTION 2:
    $data = array (
        "installInHw":"true",
        "node" => array ("id","..."),
        "..":".."
    );
    $str_data=json_encode($data);

    ..SAME THINGS..
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str_data);

    ...SAME THINGS..

In both cases, I don't receive errors, but the flow isn't installed on the controller.
Using the command line it works, so I think that this is a php-curl problem.

Comment: @user2343788 the problem is likely because the content type wasn't set, as mentioned earlier; PHP can do whatever command line can do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody!
I solved the problem adding this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
```